# npm path and package path is not the same

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I use nvm to manage node version.

I am using node version 10.15

```
> which npm
/Users/yizhuowang/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/npm
```

However, npm installed global package for version v8.9.0

```
> npm list -g --depth 0
/Users/yizhuowang/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/lib
```

I cannot find any special configuration .bashrc or .zshrc. I use Zsh if this is something related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because I have set npm prefix.

`npm config delete prefix` fixed this issue.

```
> npm config get prefix
/Users/yizhuowang/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0
> npm config delete prefix
> npm config get prefix
/Users/yizhuowang/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0
> npm list -g --depth=0
/Users/yizhuowang/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib
└── npm@6.4.1
```